# How to get the command of a process by an established port while ss, netstat and lsof failed?

Tags: ubuntu, netstat, lsof

Recently I have noticed extremely high network usage on a ubuntu server. I identified the port with nethogs. It connects to a SMB server within my LAN. It should be connected at boot for the dozens of docker containers running on it.Since I have mounted the SMB shares on separate paths for each container, I can identify the culprit by the command establishing the connection.

However, neither did ss nor lsof nor netstat reported no PID nor the command line of the process.

```
# ss -tunarp | grep 43482
tcp   ESTAB     0      588           nuc13.home.ngs:43482                         truenas.home.ngs:445                                                           

# lsof -i :43482
# netstat -tnp | grep 43482
tcp        0 1679583 10.27.0.50:43482        10.27.0.61:445          ESTABLISHED -
```

Please give me a pointer on how to identify the culprit?

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User

Comment: You show `#` which by convention is the prompt for a root shell, but the behavior you show is absolutely typical for not being root, plus Ubuntu discourages actually being root and instead prefers using sudo. If you are not in fact root, you need to use sudo.

Comment: Yeah 'ESTABLISHED' followed by '-' is abnormal unless you aren't root.

Comment: If the kernel did mount a smb/cifs filesystem, it won't report any process. Kernel is always special. If it's userland but in an other network namespace, you won't be able to find a match. More information is required for this case.

Comment: And if you're trying to find the process *using* the remote filesystem, then the question should be made more explicit.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085
I was in fact running as root by `sudo -s`. I have tried prefix with sudo as well. The output were the same.

Comment: @A.B
 My question is, how to find the command that made a particular connection while ss, netstat and lsof failed? I am not sure how could be more explicit.

Comment: Then you won't find it because of what I wrote: the kernel never reports an associated process to a socket.

Comment: @A.B 
Thanks for your input. Or how about I put it this way. nethogs reports the process as '10.27.0.50:43482-10.27.0.61:445' and PID as '?'. Is there a way to find out the command made this connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the ps command

`ps -aux | grep 43482`

There are more tools, i personally really like htop, then you can make a tree of processes.
[image: htop]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Unfortunately, 43482 is the port number, not the PID. As far as I know, ps does not list the ports associate with a process. Could you show me how?

Comment: Yeah your right, sorry. But I think you can do it like this `lsof -i -P -n | grep <PID>`

Comment: The problem I encountered is, lsof does not list the PID. Otherwise it would have been much easier.